# bigquery group by and get all elements except the groupby value

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm dealing with a some transactional history in bigquery. The table contains two columns:
`transaction_number` and `item_id`.

I'm trying to identify two features:

1. How many (average and std) products are purchased along with a certain `item_id` in the same transaction?
2. What are the list of products purchased along with the certain `item_id` in the same transaction?

For example: if we assume these are the products purchased in the same transaction,

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      trans_num      |     item_id      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         35       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         36       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         37       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I want the first output to be

```
|----------------------|------------------|
|      item_id         |     feature_1    |
|----------------------|------------------|
|          34          |         2.5      |
|----------------------|------------------|
|          35          |         2        |
|----------------------|------------------|
|          36          |         2        |
|----------------------|------------------|
|          37          |         2        |
|----------------------|------------------|
|          38          |         2        |
|----------------------|------------------|
```

And `feature_2` should contain

```
|--------|------------|
|item_id | feature 2  |
|--------|------------|
| 34     |[35, 36, 37]|
|--------|------------|
| 35     | [34]       |
|--------|------------|
| 36     | [37, 34]   |
|--------|------------|
| 37     | [36, 34]   |
|--------|------------|
```

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
with pre_aggregation as (
  select a.trans_num, a.item_id, array_agg(b.item_id) other_items
  from `project.dataset.table` a
  join `project.dataset.table` b
  on a.trans_num = b.trans_num
  and a.item_id != b.item_id
  group by trans_num, item_id
  order by item_id, trans_num
)
select item_id,
  feature_1,
  array (
    select distinct item
    from t.feature_2 item
    order by item
  ) as feature_2
from (
  select item_id,
    avg(array_length(other_items)) as feature_1,
    array_concat_agg(other_items) as feature_2
  from pre_aggregation
  group by item_id
) t
```

if to apply to sample data from  your question

```
`project.dataset.table` as (
  select 1 trans_num, 34 item_id union all
  select 1, 35 union all
  select 2, 36 union all
  select 2, 37 union all
  select 2, 34 
)
```

output is

[image]

Comment: glad it worked for you. please consider also voting up the answer